# WPF Rectangle ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf, imagesource

i couldnt fill rectangle object with image.

```
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/WpfImageApp;component/Images/Penguins.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
ib.ImageSource = bmi;
body.Fill = ib;
```

body is Rectangle object and when i run this code, there is only black screen on window. I also couldnt see my other controllers(like buttons). any solution?

Comment: Are you sure your Uri is finding the source?

Comment: yes of course. The thing is when i set the Uri source randomly like "penguinnn.jpg" then i can see all my controls.

Comment: I don't know if this will do anything, but try making `ImageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform`.

Comment: Also, does your rectangle fill the window?

Answer (score 1):

After copying what you've done I can confirm that if the BitmapImage fails to load in the constructor you get a black window with no controls visible.

Move your code to a button that you can click AFTER the window has loaded and you'll see the correct error message.

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WpfImageApp;component\Images\Penguins.jpg'.
```

After changing your URI to `pack://application:,,,/Images/Penguins.jpg` the image loads correctly

Comment: var uriSourcee = new Uri(@"/WpfImageApp;component/Images/Penguins.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
                                    image.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSourcee); but i can fill my Image object with this url.

Comment: Try the pack uri that I've put in above, should work fine. Interesting that if it fails to load a bitmap in construction, there is no error and the whole window is black, I have no idea why that happens.

Comment: The thing is when i set the Uri source randomly like "C:\penguinnn.jpg" or "E:\penguinn.jpg" then i can see all my controls. This means my URI is true i think.

Comment: Did you try moving the image load code to a button so you can see the error it's throwing?

Comment: yes it gives same error with yours.but this URI works fine with my Image object.